# Operating over nested table items in LUA

Tags: lua, scripting

How could certain values from nested table be added using LUA.

Let's say that for an undeterminated amount of items in the list, I would like to have the result of adding all the "count" values into one variable.

In the following example which has only 2 items, the desired result would be to have a variable with the value "5" as it adds the "count: 3" and count: 2" values from "master" and "data" items respectively.

```
spec:
  nodeSets:
  - config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: true
    count: 3
    name: master
    podTemplate:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
  - config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: true
    count: 2
    name: data
    podTemplate:
      metadata:
        annotations:
          sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
```

Comment: I feel like u must being missing something, but does this do what you are looking for? `local sum = 0; for _,node in pairs(nodeSets) do sum = sum + node.count end`. You dont appear to be iterating over a nested table but simply need to index the tables sorted in `nodeSets` to get the counts.

Comment: Looks like it should work, but I got this if I try it "<string>:2: bad argument #1 to pairs (table expected, got nil) stack traceback: [G]: in function 'pairs' <string>:2: in main chunk [G]: ?"

Comment: If you took what i put verbatim, I assumed the top level structure of `nodeSets` might need to be `spec.nodeSets`. As the code in the question is not representation of a Lua table I am familiar with, cant be sure the proper path to values. 1 of my other assumption is that the line `- config` denotes the beginning of a nested table and is stored at a numeric index. If you are having further issues, please include some information about how you are loading the data structure into Lua.

Comment: I removed things very specific to my env from the example, ie the full path is "obj.spec.nodeSets". The file format is yaml where under nodeSets there is an array with 2 elements (the 2 config elements with names data and master). I'm only interested in the "count" value for each element in such array items. I'll try to make the question clearer once I see what information helps you.

Comment: if the path is `obj.spec.nodeSets` than this should work `local sum = 0; for _,node in pairs(obj.spec.nodeSets) do sum = sum + node.count end`. if your using any particular library to parse the yaml that would be good to note in the question.

Comment: It works! :) Would you mind putting that as an answer to the question? About the libraries I wouldn't know...I am trying to create a custom health check for argocd https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/resource_customizations/argoproj.io/Rollout/health.lua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a the `count` value from each of the configs you do not necessarily need to iterate over nested structures, that would require multiple nested for loops.
think of a structure like

```lua
letters = {
    a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    b = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    c = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
}
```

here we would need to 2 for loops one for retrieving the items in letters and one for retrieving all the nested contained in those items.

Your problem's solution can be done with just 1 loop. We simply need to loop through the table `nodeSets` and index the count of each of the values stored in that table.

```lua
local sum = 0; 
for _,node in pairs(obj.spec.nodeSets) do
    sum = sum + node.count 
end
```